# Trying to access IBM cloud factory repo in VScode, gives error

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ibm-cloud

Pretty simple, i have put in my IBMid login info and added a Presonal Access Token via Gitub PR.cant access repo, please help. error:

```
root@suyash:/mnt/c/Users/Home/Documents/Projects# git clone https://eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com/suyashtnt/visitor-logger-tntmaninc.git
Cloning into 'visitor-logger-tntmaninc'...
Username for 'https://eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com': suayshtnt@gmail.com
Password for 'https://suayshtnt@gmail.com@eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com': 
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.  
remote: You can generate one at https://eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com/suyashtnt/visitor-logger-tntmaninc.git/'
```

Comment: mad it better @phd

Comment: What kind of token have you created? What are the assigned privileges?

Comment: yes, all privileges

Comment: Is the email address your username for Git? It should not be the IBM Cloud username, see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-git_working

Comment: it is, how do you change credentials tho?

Comment: btw here are my (improtant)vscode settings.json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7-preview\\pwsh.exe",
    "github-pr.accessTokens": {
        "https://eu-gb.git.cloud.ibm.com/": "(public access token)"
    }
}